# Ethernet PHY design considerations

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, ethernet, phy

I've started to read about Ethernet PHYs and reading the documents and articles available on the web.

I've 2 questions:

1. I read that the IEEE 802.3 Standard specifies that the copper cables should be atleast 100m long to be supported by the PHYs. But I am not able to understand why it should be atleast 100m long? Why can't it be less that 100m?
2. In the below image of the current controlled PHYs, it is mentioned that the DNP capacitors are for extra-loading and protection purposes.

[image]

Can someone tell me what do they mean by extra loading or protection purpose? Any example of extra loading or protection can be helpful in my understanding.

Comment: Please do not keep yout sources secret.

Comment: Can you quote the specific part of IEEE 802.3 Standard that says so? (I don't know what the license says about quoting though)

Comment: I believe you must have misread or misunderstood the standard. Most Ethernet standards using twisted pair are designed to work **up to** at least 100m with the appropriate cabling.

Comment: What is the logic behind the 100m distance? Can you explain the reason for it

Comment: @Newbie Users of ethernet expect that their 100m cables will work. If your phy is poorly designed and cannot handle 100m of cable, customers will be upset.

Comment: 802.3 what? 10BaseT 100BaseT? which substandard. I don't know of any standards that have a minimum length (you can tie phys together).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The standard requires that 100 meters must work within specs. If a device can't work within Ethernet requirements it is not an Ethernet device. If you already have a building where you have cabling with 90 meters inside walls, then you can't buy a device that only works for 50 meters. Specs and standards are there that we can be sure that every device that is built to a standard will work in an environment that is built to a standard. For example, gigabit Ethernet requires certain cabling to support 100m and if the cabling is poor and out of spec it does not have to work at all.
2. That's specific to whatever PHY you are using and has nothing to do with Ethernet itself. Extra capacitive load will slow down signal slew rate so if the signal slew is too fast to be within spec then capacitors are required to slow them to be within spec. The caps may offer slight protection from voltage spikes as they are slowed down too.